# React Js drag and drop github project not working

Tags: reactjs, github, drag-and-drop, command-prompt, windows-7-x64

Environment:

OS: Windows 7, 64-bit

Tried to install github project [react-drag-and-drop](https://github.com/asbjornenge/react-drag-and-drop).

**Followed procedure:**

1. Downloaded project as zip and extracted into `C:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs` folder.
2. In command prompt, opened the folder location, `C:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs\react-drag-and-drop-master`.
3. Pasted and run the given command `npm install react-drag-and-drop` in command prompt.

**Showing error as shown below:**

[image]

How to **solve the error** and install that project..?

And also how to **run the project in browser**..?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are installing `react-drag-and-drop` module inside itself that's why it is giving the error.

Your third step should be `npm install` to download the required dependencies and after than run `npm start`.

This should work for you.

Comment: @ Ritesh Bansal ... little bit confusion in your answer.. Please explain in detail.. I am getting error now..

Comment: npm warn saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs\package.json' - This is due to while i trying npm install inside `C:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs`

Comment: Right. You have to do that in `C:\xampp\htdocs\reactjs\react-drag-and-drop-master`